# How should I think about the parameters of fread()?

Tags: c++, c, io, buffer, fopen

It's easy to find popular conventions for C-style I/O. What's more difficult is finding explanations as to *why* they are such. It's common to see a read with statements like:

```
fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, ptr);
```

- How should a programmer think about using the parameters *size* and *n* of fread()?
- For example, if my input file is 100 bytes, should I opt for a larger size with fewer n or read more objects of a smaller size?
- If the size-to-be-read and n exceed the byte-size of an input file, what happens? Are the excess bytes that were read composed, colloquially speaking, of "junk values"?

Comment: "It's easy to find popular conventions for C-style I/O" - from your post, popular but wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong and you should always examine the return value of  read functions such as fread.

Comment: Absolutely, which explains the desire for an intuitive explanation. I updated my question to focus on fread().

Comment: Which language: C or C++?

Comment: The syntax focuses on C-style I/O, but my thinking is that the intuition extends across both languages. If this is wrong, I can remove C++ from the tag list.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Following the OP's edit, the dupe is not applicable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
size_t fread(void * restrict ptr, size_t size, size_t n, FILE * restrict stream);
```

> How should a programmer think about using the parameters size and n of fread()?

When reading into an array:

`size` is the size of called pointer's de-referenced type.

`n` in the number of elements.

```
some_type destination[max_number_of_elements];
size_t num_read = fread(destination, sizeof *destination, max_number_of_elements, inf);
printf("Number of elements read %zu\n", num_read);

if (num_read == 0) {
  if (feof(inf)) puts("Nothing read as at end-of-file");
  else if (ferror(inf)) puts("Input error occurred");
  else {
    // since sizeof *destination and max_number_of_elements cannot be 0 here
    // something strange has occurred (UB somewhere prior?)
  }
```

> For example, if my input file is 100 bytes, should I opt for a larger size with fewer n or read more objects of a smaller size?

In the case, the size of the data is 1, the max count 100.

```
#define MAX_FILE_SIZE 100
uint8_t destination[MAX_FILE_SIZE];
size_t num_read = fread(destination, sizeof *destination, MAX_FILE_SIZE, inf);
```

> If the size-to-be-read and n exceed the byte-size of an input file, what happens?

The destination is not filled.  Use the return value to determine.

> Are the excess bytes that were read composed, colloquially speaking, of "junk values"?

No.  There values before `fread()` remain the same,  (as long as the return was not 0 and `ferror()` not set).  If the destination was not initialized/assigned, then yes, it may be though of as junk.

---

Separate `size, n` allows `fread()` to function as desired even if `size * n` overflows `size_t` math.  With current flat memory models, rarely is this needed.

Answer (score 0):

First, the `while (!feof(ptr))` is **wrong** and a really bad anti-pattern. There are situations where it can work, but it's almost always gratuitously more complicted that correct idiomatic usage. The return value of `fread` or other stdio read functions **already tells you if it didn't succeed**, and you usually need to be able to handle that immediately rather than waiting for the next loop iteration to start. If whatever resource you're learning from is teaching this `while (!feof(ptr))` thing, you should probably stop trusting it as a source for learning C.

Now, on to your specific question about the `size` and `n` arguments: having them separate is completely gratuitous and not useful. Just pass the desired length to read for one of them, and `1` for the other. If you want to be able to determine how many bytes were already read if you hit end-of-file or an error, you need to pass `1` for `size` and the requested number of bytes as `n`. Otherwise, if any read shorter than expected is an error, it sometimes makes sense to switch them; then the only possible return values are 1 and 0 (success and error, respectively).

For an understanding of *why* it's the case that how you use these two arguments don't matter, all the stdio read functions, including `fread`, are specified as if they happened via repeated calls to `fgetc`. It does not matter if you have `size*n` such calls or `n*size` such calls, because multiplication of numbers commutes.